Flutter Future<void> main() async and await problem
I am making a todo app.
I added async to my main function to use await. When I then run flutter run, I get this problem.
I don't know this happened and my code is like the tutorial video.
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:53458/Rh6K6wUiuNY=
Error
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 296:3  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 332:7                    _invokeMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50           <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                         runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 163:18                                   handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 861:44                                   handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 890:13                                   _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 666:5                                    [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 736:7                                    callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                             _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                              _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7           <fn>

My main code that has the problem:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_first_project/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter_first_project/todo_bloc/todo_bloc.dart';
import 'package:hydrated_bloc/hydrated_bloc.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensures that all the necessary Flutter bindings are initialized
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Set up HydratedBloc storage, handling any potential errors gracefully
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: await getTemporaryDirectory(),
  );


Did you test your code in emulator or simulator?

Can you please share you full main code, so that everyone can help you
